# How can I create an mid excel function that accounts for varying length of strings?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a mid formula that helps me to find the varying length of a string. The string can be between 6 or 8 digits and I can only use the mid function, the find fuction, the lens function, the trim function and left and right function , possibly in combination with each other if need be.

For example

JGKF-HGTNJKI-GJGJ

HDHF-RNHNRTTN-NUDN

LOKD-MNGLUK-OWDM

What is the mid function that I could use for each of these? Because the middle string varies in character length?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH("-", A1) + 1, SEARCH("-", A1, SEARCH("-", A1) + 1) - SEARCH("-", A1) - 1)
```

Comment: It's working great but is the search formula the same as find? Because I don't know if I am allowed to use search and furthermore, does the formula account for the varying string length of between 6 and 8 digits?

Comment: Actually I just used find instead of search and works exactly just the same. I'm assuming the find/seach functions find the hypens and then adds 1 which will always give the starting character of the string! Very smart formula, thank you so much!